# Fix python Sqlalchemy model can not insert mysql syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Python Model:

```
 class SYSLocation(SYSModel):
        __tablename__ = 'sys_location'
        rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Call:
    db.session.add(model)

It generate mysql script:

```
 INSERT INTO `sys_location` ( rank) VALUES (13000)
```

sql error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank)
VALUES (13000)' at line 1
```

I check this query run error **mysql version 8.0.11** because rank is keyword.
But this sql can run **mysql version 10.1.25-MariaDB**.
How to fix my Sqlalchemy model run all version of mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, when dealing with reserved keywords wrap it in backticks like you did for `sys_location`:

```
INSERT INTO `sys_location` (`rank`) VALUES (13000)
```

You can escape everything if you want, but it's often not necessary. Keywords are a case where it might be necessary because these keywords do change, if infrequently.

Comment: I know this query but i want fix in sqlachemy model

Comment: Maybe you need an upgraded version of that library or you need to file a bug report if this isn't being done automatically in the latest version of both MariaDB/MySQL and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: sqlalchemy upgraded  fix my error. Thanks for your's help